# User cannot execute a command when I already specified it in /etc/sudoers

Tags: unix

Hello I want to run the following command as a user called arago:

```
`echo 1SgOSWjT | passwd --stdin JohnDoe`
```

This is to change the password for the user John Doe. However I get the following message:

*Only root can do that.*

I modified the /etc/sudoers file as follows:

```
`User_Alias ADMINS = arago`
`Cmnd_Alias LOCATE = /usr/bin/passwd`
`ADMINS ALL = NOPASSWD: LOCATE `
```

Why can I not still run the passwd command?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need

```
 echo 1SgOSWjT | sudo passwd --stdin JohnDoe
```

but it is a very bad habit that you are taking.

BTW, you might install the [super](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/super) package or the [ninja](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ninja) package and use it instead of `sudo`

I believe however that your entire approach is a security risk.

Comment: can i do it without the sudo? as the sudo command requires a tty and I am not typing it out, it is executed in a script.